# linking error with cmake - fPIC

Tags: cmake

I am having the following while making from source that also uses some static library during compilation. Here is the error:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld:/home/sajjad/Documents/Course/graphics/cmu/assignments/asst1_drawsvg/lib/libCMU462.a(base64.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol`_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
```

It has already been discussed here before, it says that I am trying to  - "Linking dynamically against static archives". And it asking to compile with -fPIC while creating the archives. But I got the source with already generated .a (archive) file.

What flag do I have to pass inside cmake to build against a static library.

Comment: `it says that I am trying to - "Linking dynamically against static archives"` - Actually, it says that you attempt to link an object with PIC against an object which doesn't support PIC. Whether the first or the second object is part of a static or dynamic library is unrelated. As you cannot enable PIC support for the second object (which is part of your `.a` file), you need to disable that option for the first object, which is created by CMake. E.g. by placing `set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE OFF)` before `add_library` call.